# Facebook JS Share Dialog and Timeline select

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk, share

I have created a button on a test website which gets the user to post a custom Open Graph story using the Facebook Javascript SDK. (*** is going to an event).

[image: robthwaites.com/contactinsydney/]

[image: Share Dialog]

However, my users do not get the option to post this action to their Groups Timeline, or share on a friends timeline – see the below Facebook sharer dialog, (where you are always sharing a link – I don't think you can use Custom Open Graph actions with the Sharer).

[image: Facebook standard sharer Timeline select]

I've looked all over the Docs and can't seem to find a way to make this functionality happen – trying to avoid users having to login to my site with Facebook/ generate a user access token.

Any solution?